# Arcgis JS API WMS Layer zoom without basemap

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wms, zoom

I have an OGC WMS resource which I am adding to a map without any basemap. To view this resource I have to zoom in, so I have decided to set a center point and zoom to this point.

The problem is that instead of zooming in to the point I have set, it zooms out  because the map has -1 zoom value.

I would like to know if someone knows any way to avoid this and set a real zoom value to the map.

Answer (score 1):

When you set center and zoom via the map's constructor options, the map assumes web mercator and the de-facto standard map zoom levels. Probably the easiest way to do what you want is to use an [extent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/extent-amd.html) instead of using center and zoom when creating your [map](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#map1).

There's a [sample that let's you select your spatial reference and then prints the map's extent](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/fl_any_projection/) so you can create an extent from that.